# Why am i getting nosuchelementexception in my code

Tags: java

Why am i getting `NoSuchElementException`?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

class GFG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for (int k = 0; k < t; k++) {
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int xn = sc.nextInt();
            int yn = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            ArrayList<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(2000);
            ArrayList<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(2000);
            int a[] = new int[2000];
            int b[] = new int[2000];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                a[i] = sc.nextInt();
                l1.add(a[i]);
            }
            sc.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                b[i] = sc.nextInt();
                l2.add(b[i]);
            }
            int tip = 0;
            while ((xn > 0) && (yn > 0)&& (!l2.isEmpty())&& (!l1.isEmpty())) {
                int pi = l1.indexOf(Collections.max(l1));
                if (l1.get(pi) >= l2.get(pi)) {
                    tip += l1.get(pi);
                    xn--;
                } else {
                    tip += l2.get(pi);
                    yn--;
                }
                l2.remove(pi);
                l1.remove(pi);

            }
            if (yn > 0) {
                while ((yn > 0) && (!l2.isEmpty())) {
                    tip += Collections.max(l2);
                    l2.remove(l2.indexOf(Collections.max(l2)));
                    yn--;
                }
            } else {
                while ((xn > 0) && (!l1.isEmpty())) {
                    tip += Collections.max(l1);
                    l1.remove(l1.indexOf(Collections.max(l1)));
                    xn--;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(tip);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Runtime Error: Runtime ErrorException in thread "main"
>     java.util.NoSuchElementException  at
>     java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)  at
>     java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)     at
>     java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
>     java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
>     GFG.main(File.java:22)
> ```

Comment: If you write your code so no one can read it, it's going to be tough for people to help you.

Comment: Because, obviously, the element did not exist

Comment: what do you input to have this error?

Comment: My input is: 1            15  9  9                 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15    15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some logs here:

```
  int tip = 0;
  while ((xn > 0) && (yn > 0)) {
    System.out.println("l1:"+l1);
    System.out.println("Collections.max(l1):"+Collections.max(l1));
    int pi = l1.indexOf(Collections.max(l1));
```

Entring `1 15 9 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`
I get a different error.

It prints out:

```
l1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
Collections.max(l1):15
l1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
Collections.max(l1):14
l1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
Collections.max(l1):13
l1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
Collections.max(l1):12
l1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
Collections.max(l1):11
l1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Collections.max(l1):10
l1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Collections.max(l1):9
l1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Collections.max(l1):8
l1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Collections.max(l1):7
l1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Collections.max(l1):6
l1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Collections.max(l1):5
l1:[1, 2, 3, 4]
Collections.max(l1):4
l1:[1, 2, 3]
Collections.max(l1):3
l1:[1, 2]
Collections.max(l1):2
l1:[1]
Collections.max(l1):1
l1:[]
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
    at java.util.Collections.max(Collections.java:669)
    at GFG.main(GFG.java:31)
```

The problem is that you are calling `Collections.max` on en empty list.

Comment: i have edited, please tell me again. But now it is showing same error for for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                a[i] = sc.nextInt();
                l1.add(a[i]);
            }           for a very large input (in the range of int only)

Comment: for following input it is showing error:     1    105 55 55        35 4 74 26 85 0 23 67 2 101 72 71 12 51 66 66 47 46 17 45 65 38 51 96 40 89 22 84 59 69 77 61 27 39 99 69 89 84 91 70 26 85 81 97 87 104 44 29 9 38 97 20 10 28 57 81 18 76 38 93 103 6 59 101 44 60 44 87 33 24 50 67 98 49 2 99 73 91 81 13 37 73 26 60 8 38 6 63 49 52 50 59 78 57 39 30 58 92 60 15 87 89 14 86

Comment: 80 43 25 45 31 10 0 82 8 86 20 88 57 14 103 84 24 63 82 22 32 17 47 57 4 63 15 104 14 66 25 26 96 51 98 64 59 33 25 91 99 84 67 55 57 17 50 81 8 77 20 63 51 2 103 1 90 52 93 64 77 1 59 89 26 102 88 80 18 54 93 60 81 87 59 58 11 8 46 14 5 58 45 17 81 68 54 93 18 95 6 35 14 3 11 49 81 84 97 53 65 41 34 82 64

Comment: it misses one value, if I add one (55 for example) it prints `7634`